# Resolving chef-solo cookbook dependencies

Tags: dependencies, chef-infra, chef-solo, cookbook

I am trying to run chef solo on my workstation to apply some settings locally. My recipe depends on several external cookbooks that I specify in both metadata.rb and Berksfile. The chef-client run fails with the error message below.

I'd like to know if there is a way to download dependencies automatically when chef-solo runs?

```
user@ubuntu:~/chef-solo$ chef-solo -c solo.rb -j solo.json

Starting Chef Client, version 12.8.1
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...

Running handlers:
[2016-03-28T16:32:36+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2016-03-28T16:32:36+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 03 seconds
[2016-03-28T16:32:36+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /home/user/chef-solo/chef-stacktrace.out
[2016-03-28T16:32:36+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2016-03-28T16:32:36+00:00] ERROR: Cookbook apt not found. If you're loading apt from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
```

solo.rb

```
root = File.absolute_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
file_cache_path root
cookbook_path root + '/cookbooks'
```

solo.json

```
{
    "run_list": [ "recipe[test::default]" ]
}
```

Berksfile

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'

cookbook 'apt'
metadata
```

metadata.rb

```
name 'test'
maintainer 'The Authors'
maintainer_email 'you@example.com'
license 'all_rights'
description 'Installs/Configures test'
long_description 'Installs/Configures test'
version '0.1.0'

depends 'apt'
```

Comment: Nice job putting this question forward in a well formated SO question, it actually helped me reach a solution for myself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Berkshelf is a popular tool in the Chef world to automate the installation of cookbook dependencies (the `Berksfile` you mentioned is related to this).  If it isn't already, install berkshelf.

```
$ gem install berkshelf
```

Notice in your `solo.rb` file the line that says...

```
cookbook_path root + '/cookbooks'
```

...that's where Chef wants you to put the dependencies.  Without Berkshelf, you would need to use knife to install apt into that cookbooks folder.  (Note: cookbooks/ must be a git repo...)

```
$ knife cookbook site install apt
```

But since you have a Berksfile, you'll probable want to use the command below in the same folder your Berksfile is in...

```
$ berks vendor ../
```

That will install the dependencies for the current folder in the parent directory.  You might need to specify a different location depending on where your root `cookbooks` folder is.

You might also be wondering why you have to specify the dependencies twice, once in your `Berksfile` and once in your `metadata.rb` file.  Me too ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built-in to chef-solo for this as download management is one of the things chef-client handles for you so you are specifically opting out of that feature. It's pretty easy to make a wrapper script that call`berks vendor cookbooks/` though, and then aim chef-solo at that folder.